# make all elements in views 'gone'

Tags: android

I have an overflow menu and one of the options is 'delete list'. When the user presses it, I want it so all the elements that the user added onto the screen, disappear/go 'gone'.

when I run my code though, that doesn't happen. the first time I press 'delete list', it deletes one set of elements, then I press delete list again, and nothing disappears.

Is my logic correct here?

Please see the section `else if (id == R.id.action_delete)`

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent startSettingsActivity = new Intent(this, settings.class);
            startActivity(startSettingsActivity);
            //start the settings activity here.
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
            //code to delete list here.   
            final int listSize = mViews.size();
            if (listSize > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
                    mCheckboxes.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinners.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mViews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mTextviews.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mEdittexts.get(listSize - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

create xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:minHeight="170dp"
    tools:context=".create"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    >


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="438dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/my_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/verticalLayout"
                android:layout_below="@id/view2">

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>






    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorCreate"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorBackground"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/subheading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:background="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:background="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/done_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/aisle_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/qty_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/droid_sans"
        android:text="@string/item_label"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what  is the parent layout of these views elements?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like you should replace `listSize - 1` with `i` in statements inside for loop. Make it clear what `mViews` and `mCheckboxes`, etc. are and relation among them.

Comment: they are all being added to my_linearlayout, a layout i have in my xml if thats what you mean @faiiziiawan

Comment: I change them all to `i` @NabinBhandari but then when I press delete list, nothing happens..

Comment: post your complete code.

Comment: @Magic_Whizz what do `mViews` and `mCheckboxes` contain and how are they related?

Comment: Try to set an id on eachtime user add an element.Then delete it by using that id

Comment: @NabinBhandari mViews and mCheckboxes contain the views and checkboxes that are created when the user presses the FAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {

    for(int j=0; j<mCheckboxes.size(); j++){
    mCheckboxes.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mSpinners.size(); j++){
    mSpinners.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mViews.size(); j++){
    mViews.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mTextviews.size(); j++){
    mTextviews.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mEdittexts.size(); j++){
    mEdittexts.get(j).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }         

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
it will delete all the view from list. there is no need to calculate mViews.size().
```

Comment: that didn't work,,one just disappears then it never changes

Comment: before using this you have to add all views in appropriate list. and when delete item clicked, then make visibility gone all the items from list.

Comment: please change listsize with j in each loop.else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
    for(int j=0; j<mCheckboxes.size(); j++{
    mCheckboxes.get(j- 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mSpinners.size(); j++{
    mSpinners.get(j - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mTextviews.size(); j++{
    mTextviews.get(j - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<mEdittexts.size(); j++{
    mEdittexts.get(j - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }         
                                   
 }

Comment: look at the above code. I have edited that. This will work.

Comment: thanks. I'll have a go at it. btw you were missing brackets in the code so i added them in

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple

assign an ID to this `LinearLayout` (parent of your Views items like spinner,check box as from your code)

then get the layout in your code as

```
Linearlayout ll = findViewById(R.id.yourLinearlayoutID);
```

then you need to call this line in on pressing the delete

```
else if (id == R.id.action_delete) {
        //code to delete list here.
                ll.setVisibilty(View.GONE); // i am supposed that the for loop you added to remove multiple values if not then add them back
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hope helping

Comment: hi ,that worked , and seems like much better logic lol. However, when I press delete list, yes, all elements disappear which is good, but then when I press the FAB button to add elements again, they do not appear. This is because the linearlayout is gone?

Comment: is there a way to set linearlayout to visible again? like so I can set it visible when the FAB is pressed

Comment: yes call ll.setVisibility(VIew.Visible) in FAB button click action

Comment: hmm ok that works but all the old items that went `GONE` are appearing again. is there a way to make them like, forever gone instead of just `gone`? Like so they never come back again?

Comment: i dont understand. can you please post the XML code too

Comment: right so, when I press 'delete list' all the spinners that the user added by pressing the FAB have disappeared. good. but then when I press the FAB to add a item, the old spinners appear as well. because I have set it to VISIBILE. So how can I make it so those items that i was suppose to 'delete' are gone forever? like deleted? that was what I was trying to do In my post.

Comment: spinners are created when user presses fab, not in th xml

Comment: ok then you need to add the one more line reinitialize you layout param in the FAB click action. the pram in which you are adding spinner items at run time

Comment: or you can just reinitialize your pram in the delete action and then you dont need to play with visibility ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179443/discussion-between-faiizii-awan-and-magic-whizz).

Comment: I posted inchat

Comment: in order to delete the list, gone for ever you can do this,on button click 
btn.setonClickListener(new onClickListener(View view){
mList.clear();
adapter.notifidatasetchanged();
});

this will remove all items from the list